# Can you replace ^13 paragraph markers with ^p paragraph markers in MS Word using Interop?

Tags: c#, ms-word, interop, office-interop

I am wanting to replace all the substitue code for paragraph markers (^13) with the normal paragraph marker code ^p in a Microsft Word document, using C# and Interop.

I am have been using the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Selection.Find.Execute() method.

For example..

```
    .Application.ActiveWindow.Selection.Find.Execute(
               ref findText,
               ref matchCase,
               ref matchWholeWord,
               ref matchWildcards,
               ref matchSoundsLike,
               ref matchAllWordForms,
               ref findForward,
               ref findWrap,
               ref findFormat,
               ref replaceText,
               ref replaceAll,
               ref missing,
               ref missing,
               ref missing,
               ref missing);
```

- findText = "^13"
- matchCase = true
- matchWholeWord = true
- matchWildcards = true
- matchSoundsLike = false
- matchAllWordForms = false
- findForward = true
- findWrap = WdFindWrap.wdFindContinue
- findFormat = false
- replaceText = "^p"
- replaceAll = WdReplace.wdReplaceAll

Using the code above, the ^13 markers are not being replaced by ^p markers.

Does anyone know how I can rectify this?

Comment: When I used \r (rather than ^13) as the value for findText and ^p as value replaceText then the above code worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check my  codes below:

```
 // Create the Word application and declare a document
            Word.Application word = new Word.Application();
            Word.Document doc = new Word.Document();

            // Define an object to pass to the API for missing parameters
            object missing = System.Type.Missing;

            try
            {
                // Everything that goes to the interop must be an object
                object fileName = @"D:\test.docx";

                // Open the Word document.
                // Pass the "missing" object defined above to all optional
                // parameters.  All parameters must be of type object,
                // and passed by reference.
                doc = word.Documents.Open(ref fileName,
                    ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                    ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                    ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                    ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

                // Activate the document
                doc.Activate();

                // Loop through the StoryRanges (sections of the Word doc)
                foreach (Word.Range tmpRange in doc.StoryRanges)
                {
                    // Set the text to find and replace
                    tmpRange.Find.Text = "xml";
                    tmpRange.Find.Replacement.Text = "XML";

                    // Set the Find.Wrap property to continue (so it doesn't
                    // prompt the user or stop when it hits the end of
                    // the section)
                    tmpRange.Find.Wrap = Word.WdFindWrap.wdFindContinue;

                    // Declare an object to pass as a parameter that sets
                    // the Replace parameter to the "wdReplaceAll" enum
                    object replaceAll = Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll;

                    // Execute the Find and Replace -- notice that the
                    // 11th parameter is the "replaceAll" enum object
                    tmpRange.Find.Execute(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                        ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                        ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref replaceAll,
                        ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
                }

                // Save the changes
                doc.Save();

                // Close the doc and exit the app
                doc.Close(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
                word.Application.Quit(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                doc.Close(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
                word.Application.Quit(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("D:\\test.docx");
            }
```

One more thing: Note here: using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

Comment: I tried the code you provided but it did not work. It seems to be very similar to the code I provided but calls the Find method for each StoryRange, rather than the entire document. The link you provided was a 3rd party solution which I did not want to pay for. Thanks however.

Comment: I found that both my and your code worked when I tried to replace the correct character. It seems that ^13 is equivalent in VBA to Chr(13) which in turn is equivalent to \r in .NET. So I needed to replace \r with ^p and it worked

Answer (score 0):

If i'm not mistake you can't call find and replace for paragraph but you can change style of them [paragraph](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc850838.aspx)